# Use spines and tick_params in Matplotlib style sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following Python 3 code for generating a plot with `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

py.figure(1)
py.plot(x, y, c='g', lw=2)
py.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
py.title('Plot Title')
py.ylabel('Y label')
py.xlabel('X label')
py.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
py.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
py.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
py.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
py.tick_params(top='off', right='off', bottom='off', left='off')
py.grid()
py.show()
```

This is my preferred configuration for creating plots with no axis borders or tick marks. Only the axis labels, title, and grid remain. Instead of writing the `spines` and `tick_params` for every plot figure, I tried to add the parameters to a `mplstyle` file. However, the style file doesn't support these features. Is there a way to make this the default configuration for all figures?

Comment: There is a PR a while ago from the prettyplotlib author (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2702) but it needs a bit more work to get merged.

Comment: What you can do to make the style file support these features is to help add them!  We are pretty friendly and welcome new contributors.

Comment: @tcaswell Well I've answered my own question. Instead of using `spines` and `tick_params` I can use the `axes.linewidth` and the `major.width` for the x and y tick marks. See my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `axes.linewidth` and the `major.width` parameters in the style sheet, I'm able to replicate the same effects as the `spine` and `tick_params`.  The following is what I am currently using in my style sheet to get the desired effects:

```
lines.linewidth : 2

axes.grid : True  
axes.linewidth : 0

xtick.major.width : 0
ytick.major.width : 0

grid.color : black
```

And here is the plot that the style creates:

[image]